# Replace 5-pin push button in my laptop

Tags: button, laptop

I have a 5 pin push button in my laptop, that doesn't work.

I have to replace that button, but in my town I don't have any in stock and I can't wait for the delivery from China.

How can I replace this button by wiring the pins? **I just need to boot the laptop once**.

I will unsolder this button now. [This is a video with the same issue](https://youtu.be/Nx__o8Em_HE?t=3m56s)

**There is a photo of the button:** [image]
Thank you.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - I am trying to understand the reason this would be migrated to Superuser. This has something to do with electronics it seems ideal at its original home.

Comment: Repair questions are off-topic on EE.SE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The switch is probably a SPST-NO tact switch with an earth connection to the metal top (for ESD protection reasons). The earth connection would be the center connection on the right.

If you want to simulate the switch closure you can short either of the two left to either of the two right (top/bottom) connections via a switch. There is no necessity to remove the existing switch unless it is shorted (unlikely). [Here](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/APEM%20Components%20PDFs/ADTSGMW66NSV.pdf) is a datasheet from a similar product.

Schematic (in the same orientation as your photo):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link to the specifications for a button like yours.](https://www.e-switch.com/product-catalog/surface-mount/product-lines/tl3303-series-6mm-x-6mm-smt-tact-switch)  It includes a schematic and a layout for the switch.
One side has three pins.
The one in the middle is not connected.
Short the other two pins on that side to turn on your laptop.